# Renaming long file names in bulk

Tags: linux, rename, filenames

I have file names like:

```
5_END_1033_ACAGTG_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
5_END_1033_ACAGTG_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
40_END_251_GTGAAA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
40_END_251_GTGAAA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I want something like:

```
END_1033_R1.fastq.gz
END_1033_R2.fastq.gz
END_251_R1.fastq.gz
END_251_R2.fastq.gz
```

Are there good ways to rename these files in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a loop to extract the important part of the filename:

```
for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | sed -re 's/^([^ACAGTG]+).*(R[1-3]).*/\1\2\.fastq\.gz/g'); echo $newname; done
```

This will simply give you a new list of filenames.  You can then move them:

```
for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | sed -re 's/^([^ACAGTG]+).*(R[1-3]).*/\1\2\.fastq\.gz/g'); mv $file $newname; done
```

To break this down a little:

- loop over the *.gz files
- create a variable which strips out the unnecessary content from the name
- move the file name to that new name

I expect there are better ways to do this, but it's what I came up with off the top of my head.

Test:

```
$ ls
40_END_251_GTGAAA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  40_END_251_GTGAAA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  5_END_1033_ACAGTG_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  5_END_1033_ACAGTG_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz

$ for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | sed -re 's/^([^ACAGTG]+).*(R[1-3]).*/\1\2\.fastq\.gz/g'); echo $newname; done
./40_END_251_R1.fastq.gz
./40_END_251_R2.fastq.gz
./5_END_1033_R1.fastq.gz
./5_END_1033_R2.fastq.gz

$ for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | sed -re 's/^([^ACAGTG]+).*(R[1-3]).*/\1\2\.fastq\.gz/g'); mv $file $newname; done

$ ls
40_END_251_R1.fastq.gz  40_END_251_R2.fastq.gz  5_END_1033_R1.fastq.gz  5_END_1033_R2.fastq.gz
```

**Note** I'm doing this in bash 4.4.5

**EDIT**
Given I'm not entirely sure which columns in the name are the most important, `awk` might work better:

```
for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | awk -F'_' '{print $2 "_" $3 "_" $6}' -); echo $newname; done
```

This will split the filename by `_` and allow you to reference the columns you want using `$X`:

```
for file in ./*.gz; do newname=$(echo $file | awk -F'_' '{print $2 "_" $3 "_" $6}' -); mv $file "${newname}.fastq.gz"; done
```

Comment: I just realised that it doesn't work in all situations like: 17_END_107A_CGATGT_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz and 29_END_4271A_ACAGTG_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz. In addition, I would prefer to take out numbers and first "_" i.e 40_, 5_, etc.

Comment: Let me see if I can adjust it :)